# Python/Kivy : How to pass TextBox value in .kv file from one class to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Can anyone tell me?
I have two file test.py and test.kv.
 I have a textBox which id : `state` . How to pass state.text value in `root.get_value(state.text)` and get value in function of  `def get_value`

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):
    state = ObjectProperty(None)

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def get_value(self,arg1):
        print(arg1)



class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    state = ObjectProperty(None)


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    state : state
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        text : "Test1"
        size_hint_x: .8
        id : state


display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'


        Rows:
            id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.get_value(state.text)

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```